# How to add instance in JAMon interface?

Tags: java, monitoring, jamon

> I have created Java web application with **JAMon API**.my question is how to add this instance in **JAMon interface**?
>   Please help me?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear what you are asking.  Are you trying to view the jamon statistics with the jamon war?

Make sure you are monitoring something.  For example are you using jamon to monitor jetty or tomcat?  Make sure you install the jamon war if it is a web application.  Make sure you install the jamon jar so it is accessible to both your application and the jamon war.  This means you should put it in the servers lib directory.

Here is more info: http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/http_monitoring.html